# How to pass an value of type enum to another enum variable?

Tags: c#

I'm getting the value of in an enum variable but while assigning it to another variable of type enum its getting 0 all the time...Here's the code i'm using , dbProperties is the object of class DBProperties which has a member of type DBType. dbProperties.DBType is always returning 0 even after assigning a value to it...Please help...!

```
DBType val = (DBType)cbDataType.SelectedIndex;
cbDataType.SelectedIndex = (int)val;
dbProperties.DBType = val;
```

Comment: What's the point of first two lines of code? Why don't you just do `dbProperties.DBType = (DBType)cbDataType.SelectedIndex`? Also, I would suggest to put the actial enum values in combobox and use them through `SelectedItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me. I think you've got a form in which you've got a dropdown combobox with items in it. So I replicated that and here is the code. The dropdown is populated with items that match (in as far as sequence) those shown in code below (the enum DBType) and shown in the first image attached

```
  enum DBType { Int, Double, Float, Bool, String  }

  class DBProperties
  {
    private DBType dbType;
    public DBType DBType { get { return dbType; } set { dbType = value; } }
  }

  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void cbDataType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      DBType val = (DBType)cbDataType.SelectedIndex;
      cbDataType.SelectedIndex = (int)val;
      var dbProperties = new DBProperties();
      dbProperties.DBType = val;
    }
  }
```

the dbProperties.DBType property is correctly set to the item selected in the dropdown.
[image]

On selecting "bool" in the dropdown the property is set to "Bool" as shown in the second image.[image]

Answer (score 0):

So dbProperties.DBType is the name of a variable which is of type DBType?

Not sure why it would be always returning 0 but I don't think it's anything to do with assigning values to enums.

Run this code for example:

```
enum DBType
{
    Int,
    Bool,
    String
}

class DBProperties
{
    public DBType DBType;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DBType d = (DBType)2;
        DBProperties p = new DBProperties();
        p.DBType = d;
        Console.WriteLine((int)p.DBType); //outputs 2
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Chris, this is deffinately not the way to explain enums since you're assigning a value of 2 which is not the value of any of the emun elements. For two elements in the enum the values (unless otherwise specified) are 0 and 1. C# allows you to (wrongly) assign values outside the bounds of th enum (sadly). If you assign the first variable to a 1 and then remove the cast to int in th eConsole.Writeline() call, you'll see it output "Bool" instead of "2".

Comment: Yes, I know, I was only creating a more complete version of the code already provided to prove that it wouldn't output 0.

Comment: Constructor used in DBProperties class.
private DBType dbType = new DBType();
        public DBType DBType
        {
            get
            {
                return dbType;
            }
            set
            {
                dbType = DBType;
            }
        }

i tried that piece of code but still its not working...is it anything wrong with with my DBProperties class?

Comment: @user654748 can you show the actual class definition in your original question please. What you've pasted here is not valid C# code.

Comment: @user654748, I've modified my answer to include a class definition of DBProperties that does not use automatic property get;set;

Comment: Thank you all for your help...It was a mistake in the get set property i used in the DBProperties class. i called the DBType member instead of value..

Comment: @Shiv, Hey, I thought you said my answer was bad because it cast an int to an enum? Nice to see that didn't stop you from copying my answer, with the exception of making it a forms app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be much more clear and specific with your question in order for people to help you.

Are you sure `val` is not always zero?  If you always select the first choice in the drop down box, selectedIndex will always be zero.